# Using DimCalendar update days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-warehouse

In DWH (SQL Server) i have two tables:

DWH.Days

| DayStart | DayStop | DaysBetween |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-21 | 2022-04-24 | null |
| 2022-03-12 | 2022-04-27 | null |
| 2022-04-21 | 2022-04-24 | null |
| 2022-03-01 | 2022-04-22 | null |

and
DWH.Calendar

| Date | IsHoliday? |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-11 | yes |
| 2022-05-12 | no |
| 2022-05-13 | yes |
| 2022-05-15 | no |

I need to update DWH.Days.DaysBetween as a number of days between DayStart and DayStop where DWH.DimCalendar.IsHoliday?='no'. I don't have premission change the data model. I don't have any ideas how to do it, any ideas?

Comment: Do you want your sample to data to have ranges that actually include the dates in the calendar table?

Comment: Yes, because [IsHoliday?] column is updated by other person

Comment: Take the first row of your Days table (what a bizarre design) and join it to your Calendar table based on the calendar date between the start and end dates - how many rows are in the resultset? Maybe outer join? You could count or sum those rows conditionally as a starting point.

Comment: What I mean is, given the sample data, none of the rows from the calendar table match the range of days in the days table. So if you want a range of days in April and your only holidays shown are in May, what query could possibly exclude holidays that aren’t within the start and end?

Comment: your data is template am I correct?since 2022-04-21  2022-04-24 is twice in table.

Answer (score 0):

your data

however there exist numerous issues regarding your sample data

```
declare @Days table (
  DayStart DATE NOT NULL, 
  DayStop DATE NOT NULL, 
  DaysBetween VARCHAR(40)
);
INSERT INTO @Days (DayStart, DayStop, DaysBetween) 
VALUES 
  ('2022-04-21', '2022-04-24', NULL), 
  ('2022-03-12', '2022-04-27', NULL), 
  ('2022-04-21', '2022-04-24', NULL), 
  --repeated data it should be deleted
  ('2022-03-01', '2022-04-22', NULL);
declare @Calendar table(
  Date DATE NOT NULL, 
  IsHoliday VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Calendar (Date, IsHoliday) 
VALUES 
  ('2022-05-11', 'yes'), 
  --actual values
  ('2022-05-12', 'no'), 
  --actual values
  ('2022-05-13', 'yes'), 
  --actual values
  ('2022-05-15', 'no'), 
  --actual values
  ('2022-04-23', 'yes'), 
  --added values for test. it can be deleted.
  ('2022-03-10', 'no'), 
  --added values for test. it can be deleted.
  ('2022-03-14', 'yes'), 
  --added values for test. it can be deleted.
  ('2022-04-22', 'no'), 
  --added values for test. it can be deleted.
  ('2022-03-15', 'no');
```

first you should use `cross join` for satisfy the Condition *DayStart<Date<DayStop and IsHoliday='no'*. then use `subquery` and `DATEDIFF` and `group by` as follows

```
SELECT Daystart,
       Daystop,
       Datediff(d, Daystart, Daystop) - Count(Isholiday) AS DaysBetween
FROM   (SELECT Daystart,
               Daystop,
               Daysbetween,
               Isholiday
        FROM   @days d,
               @Calendar c
        WHERE  d.Daystart < c.Date
               AND d.Daystop > c.Date
               AND c.Isholiday = 'no') a
GROUP  BY Daystart,
          Daystop
```

Comment: Why cross join especially an old-fashioned `,` comma join? Why not a normal join `FROM @days d JOIN @Calendar c ON d.Daystart < c.Date AND d.Daystop > c.Date` Also you need to remove the condition `AND c.Isholiday = 'no'` and then do `- COUNT(CASE WHEN Isholiday = 'yes' THEN 1 END)`